# Rendering Problems and Gradle Sync Issue

Tags: gradle, rendering

Absolute Newbie ... Would be very grateful for any help

went to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

downloaded Android Studio, created new project, clicked "finish" (ie step 8 in the link)

came back with "Rendering Problems. This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio (Details)" ... clicked "details" ... "you have latest version of Android Studio"

also

Messages Gradle Sync

Warning:The project encoding (windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8).
This can lead to serious bugs.
[More Info...](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding)
Open File Encoding Settings

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem if you are targeting the recently released M preview. Try changing the target version in the Design preview to 5.1.1 or lower.

To get to the Design preview and change this setting:

1. open up an xml layout file (activity_my.xml)
2. look at the bottom and find two tabs labeled Design and Text.
3. Click Design.
4. Now in the top (on the right side) you should see a little Android guy that probably has "MNC" to the right of him. This is what you change to 5.1.1 or lower.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reponse. Appreciate it. Did as per your Answer, got back  "Rendering Problems. The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.

Comment: @antique8 did you ever get your problem solved? Your last error makes me think that you need to make sure you have an updated support library in your gradle file.

Comment: Hi codebaum thanks very much for taking the time to followup. After several hours of scouring the net found out i had to change Build Tools Version in Project Structure from 23.0.0 rc1 down to 22.0.1. That combined with your tip got me BUILD SUCCESSFUL ! thanks again

Comment: Awesome, welcome to the wonderfully complex world of Android development! :-)